# Selenium Side Runner timesout on item location whilst in IDE is found after a while

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have made a UI test utilizing Selenium IDE and I want to be able to fire it up via cli. Therefore I have installed the `selenium-side-runner` and I fire my test via the following command:

```
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox" mytest.side
```

And timesout locating the item `.tt-cursor li`:

```
    NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: .tt-cursor li

      at Object.throwDecodedError (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
      at parseHttpResponse (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
      at Executor.execute (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.336s, estimated 14s
Ran all test suites.
```

On the other hand whilst on SeleniumIDE the item is found (even though takes too long to find it). Do you know how I can fix theese types of issues or increase the timeout time for my tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BEFORE** running the test in a cli environment it required some optimizations. The particular problem that has occurred is that it takes too long to find the element.

In SeleniumIDE installed to your browser (as it iwas in my case) theese slow downs come with an usefull warning indicating you a better value to replace the element that is not found in cli.

Therefore, a good step before testing in cli is changed the element values with the reccomended xpath from the warning message and then execute via cli the tests.